# Google Cloud Platform - Retrieve External IP using Powershell

Tags: powershell, google-cloud-platform, metadata, google-compute-engine

Google has the following documentation for using powershell with GCP

[GCP Powershell](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-powershell/#/google-compute-engine/GceMetadata/Get-GceMetadata)

You'll notice the example 'Get-GceMetadata -Path "instance/hostname"' 
This will return the hostname which is great

But I'm trying to return the External IP and constantly getting error 404 not found

I've tried the following commands but no joy

```
Get-GceMetadata -path "instance/accessConfigs/externalIp"
Get-GceMetadata -path "accessConfigs/externalIp"
Get-GceMetadata -path "externalIp"
```

Any help with this would be great!

Comment: Why don't you just load all metadata and see if the IP address is in there? `Get-GceMetadata -Recurse`. That's from the page you linked.

Comment: From here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/storing-retrieving-metadata 'network-interfaces/<index>/forwarded-ips/' . Description from the link. 'A directory of any external IPs that are currently pointing to this virtual machine instance, for the network interface at <index>. Specifically, provides a list of external IPs served by forwarding rules that direct packets to this instance.'

Comment: @Swonkie that one does give me the External IP, but im then unsure on how to extract the actual IP from the returned data

Comment: You need to look at the path where the address is stored and then use that path in your `Get-GceMetadata -Path "your/path/here"` command.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
    (Get-GceInstance | where name -eq 'your_instance_name').NetworkInterfaces.AccessConfigs.NatIP
```